# Void function doing return (void)(something)

Tags: c++

I saw a few functions in an SDK I'm using do something similar to the following:

```
void foo( float& fl )
{
    if ( std::isnan( fl ) || std::isinf( fl ) )
        return ( void )( fl = 0.f );
    /*...*/
}
```

Why?

Comment: Because the author want to write this way? Why not?

Comment: there is no *functional* reason to write code this way, This works just as well: `{ fl = 0.f; return; }`

Comment: The {} keys on their keyboard were broken?

Comment: My guess is the author decided this is more readable than adding some `{ }` to encapsulate the assignment and return.  I happen to disagree.

Comment: `f1` is a reference parameter. Perhaps this is drawing attention to the fact that changing the value in the scope of this function also changes it externally.

Comment: This is a beautiful construction! I'll use it everywhere.

Comment: Classic case of "ooh I just found out I can use this 'trick' so I will now put it all over my project to show off!" without any practical rationale at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

On the face of it, someone was just being "clever". You see, there are restrictions placed on a return statement in C++

> **[stmt.return]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2) The *expr-or-braced-init-list* of a return statement is called its
>   operand. A return statement with no operand shall be used only in a
>   function whose return type is *cv* `void`, a constructor, or a
>   destructor. A return statement with an operand of type `void` shall be
>   used only in a function whose return type is *cv* `void`. A return
>   statement with any other operand shall be used only in a function
>   whose return type is not *cv* `void`; [...]

The above makes a simple `return ( fl = 0.f );` in that function illegal. Because the expression `( fl = 0.f )` (the return statement's operand) is not of type `void`. But the author of that function, maybe in an effort to conserve lines of code, or to express some sort of "elegance", decided to force the issue. Since an operand of type `void` is okay, they added a cast. That's not the only way to make the compiler submit, for instance:

```
return fl = 0.f , void();
```

That makes use of the comma operator, and the `void()` prvalue. It's not code I'd personally advocate one to write. The code in your post and this alternative are unidiomatic, confusing and misguided. Braces (`{}`) would have made that function much clearer. So while I hope you learned something about C++ from this, don't get in the habit of writing such code. Your colleagues will think more highly of you if you write code they can understand at a glance.

Comment: `s/being clever/trying to be clever/`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Better? :)

Comment: Interesting. The input was actually a Vec3 and the return was something along the effects of `return ( void )( in.x = 0.f, in.y = 0.f, in.z = 0.f );`

Answer (score 1):

```
    return ( void )( fl = 0.f );
```

> Why?

That is rather unusual code.  Casting an expression to `void` is usually done to suppress a compiler-warning -- it's an idiom that tells the compiler "yes, I know I am throwing this expression's value away -- but I'm doing it deliberately, so you don't need to warn me about it".

What is unusual there is that the author decided to do that in a `return` statement.  It would have been clearer (and logically equivalent) to write

```
{
   fl = 0.0f;
   return;
}
```

instead.  The only thing I can think of is that the function used to return a value, and perhaps the author thought he might someday want to change it to return a value again, and would therefore try to keep the code-style looking similar to that of a value-returning function?  (If so, it seems a bit "too clever" to me)

Comment: The suggested replacement code is **not quite** the same; it needs curly braces, while the original didn't. That's not an argument for writing it the original way; as this answer says, that's too clever. +1.

Comment: I liked it better without the curly braces. <g> That's a possible explanation for the odd code. If it started out as `if (whatever) fl = 0.0f;` and someone realized that it also needed to return, they might have simply changed it to `if (whatever) fl = 0.0f; return;` and found that it broke things, so they changed it to a single statement.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same as

```
void foo( float& fl )
{
    if ( std::isnan( fl ) || std::isinf( fl ) )
    {
        fl = 0.f;
        return;
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

there is no special reason to prefer one way than another.

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's question - "Why?"

Comment: @Steve only the author of that code knows the reason, I answer that there is nothing wrong doing this.

Comment: .. in which case you are answering a different question.

Comment: @paddy so I also vote to close as opinion-based. I think my answer would help someone reach here anyway.

Comment: @paddy It is not reasonable to answer every coding style, well, **it's the author's style, no special reason.** is this a good answer then? I'd add to the answer if it seems fit.